# Using row_number function to get second highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to get the second highest salary for an individual in a company. This is the specific problem I am working on:

https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/

This is the code I've already tried writing.

```
select Salary as SecondHighestSalary from
(select Salary, row_number() over (order by Salary desc) as rank 
from Employee)
where rank = 2
```

I'm getting the error message `"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ')'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)"`.

As a follow up question, how can I get it to return `NULL`, or another message, if there is no second salary in the DB (i.e, the db is one row)?

Answer (score 3):

You need an alias for the subquery:

```
select Salary as SecondHighestSalary
from (select Salary,
             row_number() over (order by Salary desc) as rank 
      from Employee
     ) e
where rank = 2;
```

Note that this returns the *second* salary.  If the highest salary has ties, then this returns the highest salary.  If you want the *second* then you can use `dense_rank()`.

Or:

```
select distinct salary
from employee e
offset 1 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Thanks. Follow up question, how can I get it to return NULL, or another message, if there is no second salary in the DB (i.e, the db is one row)?

Comment: @ivymatch . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question, not in a comment.  This question has (at least) one answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE for this but subquery can also works well:

```
with CTE as
(
select *,dense_rank() over (order by Salary desc) as rank
)

select *from CTE where rank = 2
```

The reason I use dense_rank() instead of row_number() is if there are two second highest salary(for example: $80,000, $70,000, $70,000, $60,000...) then it will output two rows. Since I didn't have a chance to look at your real data so I assume it may happen here. Otherwise, dense_rank() is similar to row_number().