# Return null when value isn't present in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing this problem here: https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/

This is the code I've already written

```
select Salary as SecondHighestSalary from
(select Salary, row_number() over (order by Salary desc) as rank 
from Employee) temp
where rank = 2
```

I want to return null if the second highest value is not present. I think I should be using CASE, or IS NOT NULL (those are the two functions I'm most vaguely familiar with). If you could provide two solutions that each utilize those functions, that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using row\_number function to get second highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57137778/using-row-number-function-to-get-second-highest-value)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the second highest salary then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

If you want to return one row, even if no row is present, use aggregation.

So:

```
select max(salary as SecondHighestSalary
from (select Salary,
             rank() over (order by Salary desc) as rnk 
      from Employee
     ) e
where rnk = 2;
```

This will return `NULL` if all salaries are the same.

Comment: The alias `rank` needs backticks since it is a reserved word and you missed a parenthesis: `max(salary`

Comment: @forpas . . . That depends on the database, so I just changed the name.

Comment: The OP's link points to MySQL, but sure it's better to rename.

Answer (score 0):

Select the 2nd salary after sorting descending.
If there is no 2nd salary the result will be `null`:

```
select (
       select distinct salary
       from employee 
       order by salary desc
       offset 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only
       ) SecondHighestSalary;
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d3c79f/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method by using max function to get second highest salary and coalesce function for returning null values:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(salary), NULL) AS second_highest_salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees);
```

you can see output here : https://leetcode.com/problems/second-highest-salary/description/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-sql-50

Comment: You wrote (in your answer): _you can see output here_ All I see is the [leetcode] problem and that webpage telling me that I have to either login or sign up. Are you sure about the link you posted in your answer?